# Can MD5 hash be inconsistent on large files (>2GB) on USB flashdrives?

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have not seen any articles dealing with this specific set of issues/questions for PowerShell in my research (no direct answers found, only slightly similar ones).

**Issue:**
I have a PowerShell test-script that compares MD5 hash content of Gold Files (Standards) on a Windows 7,8,or 10 PC to files that have been written to USB drives (Copies or Reproductions of Standards).  Basically verifying that files on the USB drive are exactly the same before sending them out the door.  USB drives are NTFS formatted, and Read-Only (or Write denied) after files are transferred to it.  If file name, size, or MD5 is different, the test-script FAILS the file.  Issue arise inconsistently with larger files (>2GB), for example "SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe".  Some pass, some do not?

When failures occur, they are consistent on what file fails (no random occurrence); however, the MD5 hash is different from the original file?  Transferring USB file to local hard drive, still produces failure when comparing.  Some USB drives with same file will pass.  Both FAIL and PASS files have the same file size.

USB drive copies are made in different department/vendor, so I do not have details on exactly how files are transferred to USB drives.

```
$fileName = "C:\DISK1\ISSetupPrerequisites\{2917C802-9F7E-4eb4-87E6-6CF7E98BAB95}\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe"

$md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider

$file = [System.IO.File]::Open($fileName,[System.IO.Filemode]::Open,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)

$cHash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($file))
```

================================

**Questions:**

1)  Are there any issues using MD5 with large files (other than the chance to produce the same hash)?  I know its a silly question, but I have to ask.

2)  Would transferring a large file (>2GB) to a USB flash drive provide a chance of altering the MD5 hash content without changing file size?  Can bits be flipped somehow by the USB micro-controller without changing file content?  Any thing different with the nature of USB data storage that could cause concern?

3)  Would the method of copying files from Gold/Standard files to the USB drive matter on a Windows system? Copy & Paste, Drag & Drop, or xcopy command, etc. (excluding indexing/meta-data; for example "systeminfo.ini")

Comment: Since you're using PowerShell 4, you should try `Get-FileHash`. If you're still getting differences, I'd suggest moving this question to http://SuperUser.com/ as it sounds more like you have a hardware or filesystem problem; a copy of your file should be identical bytes regardless of method.

Comment: Is all of this done on a single computer? Does copying these files to a different, nonlocal drive show the same symptoms?

Comment: Update:  I tracked down the equipment used to clone USB drives.  http://www.nexcopy.com/usb-duplicator/

Comment: It appeared they were deploying incorrect image settings on the NexCopy USB200PC system.  I am not familiar with these systems; however, when they changed the image deployment size from 4GB to 6GB, the copied USB files no longer had issues (or changed bits).  In summary, not a file transfer issue; not a PowerShell code issue.  (Thank you for input guys)